# how to remove jquery datatable row which is in modalForm?

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I have a datatable which is inside Modal Form and I want to remove row of datatable when #button is click after selecting of row.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalForm2" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:80%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <form  class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        <div class="modal-header">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="paymentTerm" class="col-md-2">paymentTerm</label>
        <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" id="paymentTerm" value="" class="form-control"/></div>
        <label for="orderDate" class="col-md-2">orderDate</label>
        <div class="col-md-4"><div class="input-group date datepicker" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                    <input class="form-control" id="orderDate" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></input>
                  </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="remarks" class="col-md-2">Delivery remarks</label>
        <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" id="remarks" value="" class="form-control"/></div>
        <label for="quantityRemarks" class="col-md-2">quantity In</label>
        <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" id="quantityRemarks" value="" class="form-control"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="descRemarks" class="col-md-2">All Item Remark</label>
        <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" id="descRemarks1" value="" class="form-control"/></div>
        <label for="descRemarks2" class="col-md-2">All Item Remark2</label>
        <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" id="descRemarks2" value="" class="form-control"/></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="heading">
       <i class="fa fa-table"></i>Item List<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary-outline pull-right" id="add-item"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" onclick="ClickAddItem(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Item</a>
       <Button id="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary-outline pull-left" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Remove Item</Button>       
                  </div>
         <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dataTableCreate">
                      <thead>
                        <th id="aoColumnDefs">
                        Item
                        </th>

                        <th>
                         Description
                        </th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs">
                           Code Remark
                        </th>

                        <th class="hidden-xs">
                         Rate
                         </th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs">
                          Quantity 
                        </th>
                        <th id="Amount">
                        Amount
                        </th>

                      </thead>
                      <tbody>

                      </tbody>

                    </table>

        </div>

         <div class="form-group" id ="errors">
          </div>
         </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
         <!-- <a class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a> -->
         <a class = "btn btn-default" onclick="CloseModal2(this)">Close</a> 
         <a class = "btn btn-primary" id="btn_POcreate" href="#" onclick="ConfirmCreatepurchaseOrder(this)">Save</a> 

        </div>

        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Here is some javascript function which I can select the table row but not been able to remove from datatable.

```
    var ocretetable;
 var amount;
 var aPos;
 $('document').ready(function(){
     ocretetable = $('#dataTableCreate').dataTable();   
        $('#dataTableCreate tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
             aPos = ocretetable.fnGetPosition( this );
            alert(aPos);
            console.log('clicked');
            if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
            else {
                ocretetable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }
        } );


        $('#button').click( function () {

            $('#dataTableCreate').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(aPos); 

        } );
 });
```

I don't want modal Form to close after deleting row. Kindly show me the best way to delete datatable row.

Answer (score 0):

3 simple things that can put you in the right track:

1. When you assign a variable to a DataTable, don't ever again initiate the datatable as you are doing in the `button` click event. Always use the assigned variable to invoke the DataTable once again.
2. The [docs are very explicit](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.remove%28%29) on how you can delete a row from a DataTable.
3. You have a method that makes the entire row (`tr`) clickable, and you are using a ID for the `#button`... I'm assuming the button is outside the table (or you can't click as you already have an event for the entire row... Either use other type of selection (maybe a checkbox) or you need to hold a variable that tells you what row the user selected to be deleted

in code, something like:

```
$('#button').click( function () {

  var trForDeletion = $(".datatable tr:first"); // make sure what row is
  ocretetable
    .row( trForDeletion )
    .remove()
    .draw();
});
```

Comment: the thing is after remove ,my modal form is colse automatically. How can I do in order to make modal form remian. Regards, Ruby

Comment: I think because I write in document.ready() function. Once I remove document.ready function , can't click anymore.